# quick question: how to set *.domainname.com url in django

Tags: django, url

I know there are lots of example for how to set http://domainname.com/username
url. But how to set http://username.domainname.com   url in django?

Thinking a way to have a unique url for each user as http://username.domain.com like http://garry.posterous.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first step, you need to arrange your DNS server to serve the wildcard domain; this is completely outside Django.

When you managed to do that (i.e. `dig garry.posterous.com` succeeds), then simply check for the [HTTP_HOST request variable](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) in the django view routines.

Comment: thanks, sorry, i didn't mean to serve an wildcard domain, i put wildcard meaning any characters there, i already edited my post to avoid confusion.

Comment: +1. I've implemented this in several projects using the technique Martin described, using either custom views or custom middleware to check request.META['HTTP_HOST'].

Answer (score 0):

see Using Subdomains with Django: http://www.rossp.org/blog/2007/apr/28/using-subdomains-django/